# How do I change a growth formula to calculate specific values back in time

Tags: economics

I am doing a calibration of UK's development using unified growth theory.
My formula for population growth is:

$n = [(\gamma-\lambda)^\alpha]*[(\mu * A^\epsilon)/((\delta * M^\phi)^\alpha * L^{(1-\alpha)})]$

where $A$ and $M$ are totalfactorproductivity in the agricultural and manufacturing sector, respectively and $L$ is population. (All values are in the same period)

I have caculated population growth from 1870-2010, but I need to calculate population change, $n$, from 275-1871. How do I change the formula, thus I can calculate growth backwards

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. Please check out how to use MathJax to edit your next posts. Plus, please try to add the abstract and explain your efforts

Comment: Hi. Do you have the data for the parameters in your formula for the period 275-1871?
Also, this question might be more suitable for the Economics site.